# Is there a way to change remove notification sound in react-native-firebase (background and closed app, not in foreground)?

Tags: firebase, react-native, notifications, react-native-firebase

I am going to provide a custom notification'sound to the user, includes remote notification on background received and closed app received (not include foreground), how can I to it ?

I cannot find any resources from the document that describes how to change the default sound to a custom sound when notification received from background and closed app.Seems that on these two cases, the notification sound would be controlled by the mobile devices and cannot be set manually on react-native.

I have 3 parts to handle notification as below:

//foreground

firebase.notifications().onNotification()

//background

firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened

//app closed

firebase.notifications().getInitialNotification()

What can I do to edit the notification sound to my custom sound,Thanks!

Comment: problem solved~!

Comment: hi, how did you do for the problem? Can you pls share? thanks

Comment: Hey @user3420263 can u help me I've faced the same share your answer please, thanks in advance